# exact match query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to run an exact match query in ES

in MYSQL my query would be:

```
SELECT * WHERE `content_state`='active' AND `author`='bob' AND `title` != 'Beer';
```

I looked at the ES docs here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html

and came up with this:

```
{
"from" : '.$offset.', "size" : '.$limit.',
"filter": {
"and": [
  {
    "and": [
      {
        "term": {
          "content_state": "active"
        }
      },
      {
        "term": {
          "author": "bob"
        }
      },
      {
        "not": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "title": "Beer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
    ]
  }
}
```

but my results are still coming back with the title = Beer, it doesn't seem to be excluding the titles that = Beer.

did I do something wrong?

I'm pretty new to ES

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I used this instead...

```
{
 "from" : '.$offset.', "size" : '.$limit.',
  "query": {
   "bool": {
   "must": [
    {
      "query_string": {
        "default_field": "content_state",
        "query": "active"
      }
    },
    {
      "query_string": {
        "default_field": "author",
        "query": "bob"
      }
    }
  ],

  "must_not": [
    {
      "query_string": {
        "default_field": "title",
        "query": "Beer"
      }
    }
  ]




}
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) is a pretty good concept to handle various relationship between search criteria. Have a quick look into [Query string query syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) to understand in detail about this concept

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(content_state:active AND author:bob) AND NOT (title:Beer)"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Filters are supposed to work on exact values**, if you had defined your mapping in a manner where title was a **non-analyzed** field, your previous attempt ( with filters) would have worked as well.

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "test": {
            "_all": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "properties": {
                "content_state": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "author": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```